# PHP / Wordpress / Woocommerce: Prevent url parameter from being read

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce

I was wondering if it would be possible to prevent url parameters from being read and used via PHP, specifically with Wordpress and Woocommerce.

The best example I can give is as follows, for a domain with wordpress and woocommerce installed, the following URL will add the appropriate product (with product id 999) to cart instantly:

www.example.com/?add-to-cart=999

I would like to prevent this parameter from being read if possible. All assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you rewrite the $_REQUEST and the $_GET global variables?

Comment: I would, but I fear the only way I know how to do this is by manually editing the PHP files that contain the variables and the main issue is that I don't know which files these are upon inspecting the woocommerce plugin files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, solved it, sort of. No GET Requests will go through on that particular parameter.

Edit class-wc-form-handler.php (found within the woocommerce/includes directory where your wordpress plugins are found) as follows:

find the function add_to_cart_action and add the following directly under the method declaration:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
        return;
    }
```

All done, probably not the best answer, but it gets the job done.